# 登録されたときの挙動がおかしい。

Tags: php

PHPの例の自動販売機システムの作成中で起きたことです。
操作や挙動が思ってたのよりもうまくいかないです。

①
　URLを開いた瞬間いきなりエラーメッセージが表示される。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　②
　空欄で入力するとエラーメッセージは表示されるが、同時にデータも登録されてしまう。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2回目も空欄で入力するとエラーメッセージは表示されるが、同時になぜか2つもデータも登録されてしまう。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
3回目、4回目も2回目と同様です。
　③
　データを入れて入力するとなぜか個数だけ登録できていない。
　[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　2回目でデータを入れて入力するとなぜか前回入力したデータと今回入力したデータ(個数0)が登録されてしまう。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　3回目、4回目も2回目と同様です。
関数を一緒に合体させたり、submitを押されたときに等条件を追加しましたが、データが登録できなくなったり、エラーメッセージが表示されなくなったりなどうまくいきませんでした。
　おそらくinsert_drink関数とdo_sql関数とvalidation_check関数がうまくいってないのですが直し方がわかりません。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

ソースコード
functions.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/index.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/result.php');


function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
                
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
                    
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
                
            
        }

        /*もしもisset($_POST['new_status']の中身がTRUEならば*/
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
            
            /*もしもisset($_POST['new_stock']の中身がTRUEならば*/
            if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
                $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
             }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ステータスを選択してください';
            
            
        }

            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_name, price, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);


                $sql = 'INSERT INTO stock_table(drink_id, stock, created_at, updated_at) VALUES(\''.$drink_id.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\')';

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
                    $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                    
            
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'drink_info_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                
                
            }
                $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
                
            }
}

        
// function update_drink() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

//         if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
//             if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['update_stock'])) === 1) {
//                 $update_stock = (int) cut($_POST['update_stock']);

//                 $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time;

//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
//                     $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
                    
//                     ;
                    
//                 } else {
//                     $err_msg[] = '在庫数の更新に失敗しました';
                    
                   
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                
              
//             }
//         }
//     }
// }
// function change_drink() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

//         if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
//             if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
//                 $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//                 $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

//                 $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET updated_at = \'' . $change_time . '\', status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
//                     $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
                    
//                 } else {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
//             }
//         }
//     }

//     if (count($err_msg) === 0) {
        
//         mysqli_commit($link);
//     } else {
        
//         mysqli_rollback($link);
//     }

//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, stock_table.stock, drink_info_table.status, FROM drink_info_table LEFT JOIN stock_table ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
// }



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.status,stock_table.stock
    FROM drink_info_table
    JOIN stock_table
    ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

// function id_check() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

//         $purchase_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//         if (isset($_POST['drink_id']) === TRUE) {

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($_POST['drink_id'] === ''):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
//                     break;
//                 case ($_POST['drink_id'] === NULL):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
//                     break;
//                 default:
//                     $drink_id = (int) $_POST['drink_id'];
//                     break;
//             }
//         } else {
//             $err_msg[] = '商品を選択してください';
//         }

//         if (isset($_POST['money']) === TRUE) {

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($_POST['money'] === ''):
//                     $err_msg[] = '金額を入力してください';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($_POST['money'] === NULL):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからmoneyを受信できませんでした';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['money'])) !== 1):
//                     $err_msg[] = '金額は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    
//                     break;
//                 default:
//                     $money = (int) cut($_POST['money']);
//                     break;
//             }
//         }

//         if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

//             $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price,  drink_info_table.status, stock_table.stock
//             FROM drink_info_table
//             JOIN stock_table
//             ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id
//             WHERE drink_info_table.drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

//             if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//                     $data[] = $row;
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = '情報の取得に失敗しました';
//             }

//             foreach ($data as $info) {

//                 $drink_name = $info['drink_name'];
//                 $price = (int) $info['price'];
//                 $stock = (int) $info['stock'];
//                 $status = (int) $info['status'];

//                 $remaining_stock = $stock - 1;
//                 $return = $money - $price;
//             }

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($return < 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'お金が足りません';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($remaining_stock < 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'この商品は品切れです';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($status === 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'この商品は選択できません';
                    
//                     break;
//             }

//             $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $remaining_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $purchase_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

//             if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//                 $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_history_table(drink_id, purchased_at) VALUES (' . $drink_id . ', \'' . $purchase_time . '\')';

//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'drink_history_tableへの追加に失敗しました';
                    
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableの更新に失敗しました';
//         }
        
//     }
// }

// function html_enc($text){ 
// return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// }
// }

function validation_check($link) {
   $err_msg = [];
   if (!isset($_POST['new_name']) || (isset($_POST['new_name']) && $_POST['new_name'] === ""))  {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_price']) || (isset($_POST['new_price']) && $_POST['new_price'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_stock']) || (isset($_POST['new_stock']) && $_POST['new_stock'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '個数を入力してください';
    }
    return $err_msg;

}
```

tool.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
$data = insert_drink($link);
$data = do_sql($link);
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

$data =  [
                'drink_name' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'created_at' => '',
                'updated_at' => '',
                'status' => '',
            ];

close_db_connect($link);
```

tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php require_once('../../include/model/functions.php'); ?>
    <?php
    $complete_msg = insert_drink($link);
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0) {
        foreach ($complete_msg as $complete) { ?>
            <p><?php print $complete; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>
    <?php 
    $err_msg = validation_check($link);
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>

                <?php if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ($data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

const.php

```
<?php
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];

define('DB_HOST',   ''); // データベースのホスト名又はIPアドレス
define('DB_USER',   '');  // MySQLのユーザ名
define('DB_PASSWD', '');    // MySQLのパスワード
define('DB_NAME',   '');    // データベース名

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Answer (score 1):

問題点がたくさんありそうですが、まずはアルゴリズムに注目して回答します。

プログラムを作るうえで大事なことは

「プログラム的思考でアルゴリズムを考えること」
「考えたアルゴリズムをプログラムで再現すること」
です。
なのでまずはアルゴリズムが大事です。
アルゴリズムを表現する方法は[フローチャート](https://tech-blog.rakus.co.jp/entry/202001026/flow-chart)や[アクティビティ図](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ja/uml-activity-diagram)などいろいろありますが、一旦簡略化した方法で説明します。

tool.phpとtool2.phpからアルゴリズムを確認すると以下のようになっています。

tool.php
「開始」
→「必要なファイルを読み込む」
→「データベースにつなぐ」
→「POSTだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」
→「drink_info_tableからデータを参照する」
→「tool2.phpを読み込む」
→「データベースから切断する」
→「終了」

tool2.php
→「HTMLのヘッダーを出力する」
→「POSTだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」
→「バリデーションを実行してその結果を表示する」
→「新規商品追加のフォームを表示する」
→「商品一覧を表示する」
→「終了」

となっています。これは頭の中のアルゴリズムと同じになっていますか？
まずはそれを確認してください。

まずわかりやすい問題点が「POSTだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」が2回行われています。もっと具体的に言うと、insert_drink()が2回呼ばれています。

またバリデーションが実行されていますが、バリデーションの目的は「画面にエラーのテキストを表示すること」が目的ではないです。「データベースに不正な値を入れないこと」が目的です。バリデーションの結果が×であれば、データベースに登録する処理に回してはだめです。

上記を踏まえて、処理的にはこうするべきでしょうね
tool.php
「開始」
→「必要なファイルを読み込む」
→「データベースにつなぐ」
→「POSTだったらバリデーションを実行する」
→「POSTかつバリデーションの結果がOKだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」
→「drink_info_tableからデータを参照する」
→「tool2.phpを読み込む」
→「データベースから切断する」
→「終了」

tool2.php
「開始」
→「HTMLのヘッダーを出力する」
→「バリデーションの結果を表示する」
→「新規商品追加のフォームを表示する」
→「商品一覧を表示する」
→「終了」

またtool.phpとtool2.phpと分けて記述していますが、
それが混乱するもとになっている可能性があるので、一旦まとめたソースコード（元のソースコードをまとめただけで修正の必要があります）と処理の流れを置いておきます。これをtool.phpとして実行して修正開発を試してみてください。

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
$data = insert_drink($link);
$data = do_sql($link);

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php require_once('../../include/model/functions.php'); ?>
    <?php
    $complete_msg = insert_drink($link);
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0) {
        foreach ($complete_msg as $complete) { ?>
            <p><?php print $complete; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>
    <?php 
    $err_msg = validation_check($link);
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>

                <?php if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ($data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
<?php

$data =  [
                'drink_name' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'created_at' => '',
                'updated_at' => '',
                'status' => '',
            ];

close_db_connect($link);
```

上のtool.phpの処理の流れ
「開始」
→「必要なファイルを読み込む」
→「データベースにつなぐ」
→「POSTだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」
→「drink_info_tableからデータを参照する」
→「HTMLのヘッダーを出力する」
→「POSTだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」
→「バリデーションを実行してその結果を表示する」
→「新規商品追加のフォームを表示する」
→「商品一覧を表示する」
→「データベースから切断する」
→「終了」

理想的なtool.phpの処理の流れ
「開始」
→「必要なファイルを読み込む」
→「データベースにつなぐ」
→「POSTだったらバリデーションを実行する」
→「POSTかつバリデーションの結果がOKだったらdrink_info_tableにデータを登録する」
→「drink_info_tableからデータを参照する」
→「HTMLのヘッダーを出力する」
→「バリデーションの結果を表示する」
→「新規商品追加のフォームを表示する」
→「商品一覧を表示する」
→「データベースから切断する」
→「終了」

Comment: 丁寧な解説ありがとうございます。自分の頭の中整理してやってみます